Databricks sql generate hierarchy and find the first ancestor record
looking to generate the hierarchy and find the first ancestor record using databricks SQL query joining below two tables. If one order is dependent on two orders then the baseline order will be the one with minimum created_date.
Order table:



order_id
product
created_date




69980
table
11-12-2024


69981
stool
11-15-2024


69982
phone
11-23-2024


73396
car
10-11-2024


73395
bike
11-16-2024


73397
door
11-17-2024



Connection Table:



order_id
connection_id




69980



69981
69982


69981
69980


69982
69981


73395



73396



73397
73395


73397
73396



Expected data set:



order_id
connection_id
baseline




69980
69981
69980


69981
69980
69980


69981
69982
69980


69982
69981
69980


73396
null
73396


73395
null
73395


73397
73395
73396


73397
73396
73396



baseline for 73397 is 73396 base we need to pull the connection with least created_date from connection table.

Info is missing:  1) Why connection_id = 69981 for order_id = 69980?    2) Why connection_id = null   for order_id 73396 (and 73395)

With questions remaining

Why connection_id = 69981 for order_id = 69980?
Why connection_id = null for order_id 73396 (same for order_id 73395)

Without above answer I am stuck at this:
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    orders.order_id,
    FIRST_VALUE(c1.connection_id) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY created_date)  AS connection_id,
    LAST_VALUE(c1.connection_id) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY created_date DESC)  AS baseline
  FROM orders
  LEFT JOIN connections c1 ON c1.order_id = orders.order_id

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 
    orders.order_id,
    LAST_VALUE(c1.connection_id) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY created_date)  AS connection_id,
    LAST_VALUE(c1.connection_id) OVER (PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY created_date DESC)  AS baseline
  FROM orders
  LEFT JOIN connections c1 ON c1.order_id = orders.order_id
) x
ORDER BY order_id
;




order_id
connection_id
baseline




69980
null
null


69981
69980
69982


69981
69982
69982


69982
69981
69981


73395
null
null


73396
null
null


73397
73395
73395


73397
73396
73395



see: DBFIDDLE
